# How I can break two grid column using bootstrap and css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJnY2.png)

grid break space between 2 column.

```
<section>
<div class="container mt-2">
    <div class="row justify-content-around">
        <div class="col-md-8 bg-light justify-content-around">
            <h1>Helo</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 bg-light">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone help to break two grid column.

Comment: Please describe what is actually you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use display inline-block for having the divs in a single row.

Try

.justify-content-around div {
display:inline-block
}

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by " the space " the padding added to each `div` in your row.

[image]

Then you can remove it by adding the class `no-gutters` to the `row` div.

```
    <div class="row justify-content-around no-gutters">
```

and the space between the two divs is now removed.

[image: result]

if that is not what you mean please provide a **screenshot** of your desired result.

Comment: you are most welcome. Don't forget to click the checkmark next to my answer if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section>
<div class="container mt-2">
    <div class="row justify-content-around">
        <div class="col-md-6 bg-light">
            <h1>Helo</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 bg-light">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```